# restrict jsgrid to add new row when it is empty

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I am using JSGrid in our application. When I am adding new row by clicking + button, even if data is not entered in the grid, jsgrid is adding that empty row. So, do we have a function where we can verify and restrict these sort of adding empty rows in jsgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the validate property to your required fields?

I.e.

```
fields: [
        { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
        { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50, validate: "required" }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine. but i want consolidated message instead if I have 3 columns and when I try to add empty row it is giving alert box with field is required 3times.

Comment: In that case you should be able to use the [onItemInserting](http://js-grid.com/docs/#oniteminserting) callback instead. That way you can check all your fields in the same function, and if any of the required ones are empty, cancel insertion and alert the user.

Comment: Thank you Michael Horn. Brilliantly said